Python app created using pyinstaller and universal2 mode won't start on Intel Mac
I have a Python App that I want to build for ARM and Intel Macs (universal2). I installed Python 3.11 using universal2 wheel, and also installed all necessary extensions using the corresponding universal2 wheels. The UI of the App is based on PyQt6. Everything running on a M3 iMac.
I use pyinstaller with the --target-arch universal2 option to generate an executable that runs on arm and intel Macs. On the M3 iMac this App runs fine.
On my older Intel iMac however, the App won't start. I get an ImportError for the file PyQt6/QtCore.abi3.so (and some others) stating "mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64h')". So, I assume that there was some error during creating the universal2 app via pyinstaller, and some arm64-only files where used to build the executable.
Unfortunately I have no idea why that happens and what I can do to resolve this issue. Has anybody experienced similar behaviour or knows what I am doing wrong? Thanks.
